# Sequentially rank vector

Tags: r

I have a vector of random numbers:

```
a <- rnorm(10)
```

I would like to do the following:

1. start form the first element and compare it to the second
   2.if the second element is larger than the first proceed to the third element otherwise print the position of the sequentially highest element (2)
2. if the third element is larger than the fourth, proceed to the fourth element, otherwise print the position of the sequentially highest element (3)

and so on until the sequence ends.

So for example:

if the numbers are `1 4 5 3 1`

I start by comparing 1 and 4 and since 4 is larger I proceed
then I compare 4 and 5 and since 5 is larger I proceed
then I compare 5 and 3 and since 3 is small I stop and print the position of 5 which is the position of the highest element in the sequence.

Comment: are you looking for the largest element in the sequence (which can be obtained with `which.max`) or for the last monotonic element?  I'm not sure from your question.

Comment: the last monotonic element

Comment: Please show the expected output for `c(3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1)`.

Comment: for your example the output is 1 because comparing 3 and 1 results in 3 being larger than 1 and the position of 3 is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
set.seed(1118)
s <- sample(10)
s
[1]  5  4 10  8  9  3  6  7  1  2
```

With the example above we can look use `diff` to isolate positive changes in the sequence:

```
which(diff(s) < 0)
[1] 1 3 5 8
```

**edit:**

For the first value only subset the vector of higher numbers in the sequence:

```
which(diff(s) < 0)[1]
[1] 1
```

Your original example:

```
s <- c(1, 4, 5, 3, 1)
which(diff(s) < 0)[1]
[1] 3
```

Comment: but the whole comparison process should stop immediately at 1 in your example. You start by comparing 5 and 4. 5 is larger than 4 so you stop and print the position of 5.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe using `Position`:

```
a <- c(1,4,5,3,1)

#position will find the first element in the diff(a) that is negative
#and will output its position. The vector diff is n-1 the length
#of a so this will result in printing the position required by the OP
Position(function(x) x < 0 , diff(a))
[1] 3
```

Comment: However, this is inefficient because it hides a `for` loop. A solution based on `which.max` would be the most efficient: `which.max(c(diff(x) < 0, TRUE))`.

Comment: Thanks @Roland. The question doesn't mention efficiency and `Position` is quite straightforward that's why I mentioned it. (The for-loop also stops once the condition is confirmed, so this makes it a bit faster). You could either post it as a new solution or probably @PierreLafortune could add it in his post as he is already using `which` in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

`min(which(diff(x) < 0))` should do the trick

```
x <- c(1, 4, 5, 3, 1)
min(which(diff(x) < 0))
x[min(which(diff(x) < 0))]


set.seed(1)
a<-rnorm(10)
min(which(diff(a) < 0))
```

Comment: there's only one issue. If the sequence is a<-c(1,2,3,4,5) then I get Inf but it should just be the last element

Comment: There are a number of ways you could approach it, but in all of them, you'll need to use some kind of logical control.  something like adding `if (!is.finite(position)) position <- length(x)`.  I'd suggest wrapping a few lines into a single function.